# How to implement the Django's server to listen to POST requests from Webhook? I am using NGROK to expose my localhost to the Internet

Tags: django, github, webhooks, postmessage

I have already created a Webhook in my Github repository. I have set my payload URL to:
localhost:4567/payload

As I am using my localhost, I need to expose it to the Internet. For this purpose, I am using ngrok and I have also executed this command: 
./ngrok http 4567

I am following all the steps written in this link to create a successful webhook for receiving notification whenever any action on commits is done in the repository.

Link => https://developer.github.com/webhooks/configuring/

I am using Django framework to receive POST requests from the Webhook. However, in the tutorial given in above link, they have used Sinatra (to create web application in Ruby). I am not familiar with Ruby. I wish to continue working in Django, so could you please help me how can I use Django's server to listen to POST requests from Webhook?

By far what I have done, I have got following error in my Webhook. The 'response' is given below:

```
<!doctype html5>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

    strong { font-weight: bold; }
    hr { -moz-box-sizing: content-box; box-sizing: content-box; height: 0; }
    html { font-family: sans-serif;   -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;   -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;   } body { margin: 0; }
    a { background-color: transparent; }
    a:active, a:hover { outline: 0; }
    </style>

    <style type="text/css">
        body { background-color: #f5f5f5; }
        .container { width: 500px; margin: auto; color: #444; padding: 5px; }
        a, strong { color: purple; text-decoration: none; }
        a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
        h2 { text-align: center; color: #000; }
        p { line-height: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">


<h2>Failed to complete tunnel connection</h2>
<hr />
<p>
The connection to <strong><a               
href="http://ac448203.ngrok.io">http://ac448203.ngrok.io</a></strong>
was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client,
but the client failed to establish a connection to
the local address <strong><a href="http://localhost:80">localhost:80</a>            
</strong>.
</p>
<p>
Make sure that a web service is running on
<strong><a href="http://localhost:80">localhost:80</a></strong> and that it 
is a valid address.
</p>
<p>
The error encountered was: <strong style="color: #9E2929">dial tcp [::1]:80: 
connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively 
refused it.</strong>
</p>}


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you show us the request and response that you have conveniently cut out of your screenshot. You can blur out any secrets

Comment: @CliveMakamara Actually I am new to Stack Overflow so I am not sure how to post photos on this platform. Sorry for that. I will post the response part. Thank you.

Comment: No worries I've also been a member for only a month. I just need more info to help you

Comment: You shouldn't be posting screenshots at all. Code and errors are both text, you should just copy and paste them into the question.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for the advice. I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your ngrok setup it is trying to connect port 80. Try a different version of ngrok or make sure you are really running `ngrok http 4567`

Comment: Yes, I have done it like many times (ngrok http 4567).
I have not tried a different version of ngrok. I guess I should try it. Thank you so much @Clive.